# VS 2015 and SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I've got VS2015 installed and the latest version of SQL Server Data Tools installed and can't seem to import a circa 2008 SSRS reporting project.

Or even create a new reporting project for that matter.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Zack

Answer (score 2):

As of Sep 14, 2015 Sql Server Reporting Services (SSRS) **hasn't been released** as part of SSDT 2015.

[image]

[Link to the page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2015/09/01/sql-server-data-tools-preview-update-for-august-2015.aspx).

One of the positive news from SSDT Preview update for August 2015 is now there will be only one installer for **database and BI tools**. No more [SSDT naming confusion](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2013/01/16/more-ssdt-naming-confusion.aspx) which was introduced with SQL Server 2012.

For now you have to install [SSDT-BI-2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313) or [SSDT-BI-2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843).

Answer (score 0):

SSDT is updated on July 7 2016, can be downloaded from Microsoft website https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx